# How can I create a custom shape with round edges on Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes, pen-tool

I'm trying to create a custom shape overlay in the navigation bar similar to the example below.

[image: Trying to create the shape]

I'm struggling with trying to create the radius around the bottom edges. I'm not too great with the pen tool, I find it hard to create the 'bend' of the shape. What is the best way to create this shape?

Comment: I don't think Photoshop is the best tool for this as it's primary function to work with bitmaps (photos). I know how to draw any shape with perfect geometry in Fireworks, if you're interested...

Answer (score 5):

A similar approach can be taken in Photoshop, but here is one solution done in Illustrator:

1) Draw rectangle
[image]

2) Select `rectangle > Effect > Stylize > Rounded Corners > ~10px`

[image]

3) Select Direction Arrow (a) > Grab top right corner of rectangle *holding shift
 to keep structure* and create your desired angle

[image]

4) Select `rectangle > Object > Expand Appearance` --This will make the stylized rounded corners actual points that will be used for the outline

[image]

5) Duplicate this `rectangle`(<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>copy</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to paste in front)`> Object > Transform > Reflect > Horizontal` -- set aside for now.

[image]

6) Draw new rectangle

7) Place new rectangle over original rounded corner rectangle, aligning baseline of both rectangles

[image]

8) Select both `rectangles > Pathfinder > Minus Back`  -- (ignore 2nd rectangle on top, shouldn't have included it in this screenshot)

[image]

9) Align 2nd rounded rectangle to baseline edge.
[image]

10) Select `all > Pathfinder > Divide` -- This will allow you to delete the excess area

[image]

11) `Select all > Pathfinder > Merge`
[image]

Obviously, this is not the best solution for everyone, but it should help you wrap your head around at least one way to achieve this result.  I often just need someone to get me started down a path to a solution. Hopefully this does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

### [image]

1. create a square add second one to the same path
2. transform smaller square and angle it after add to the same shape 2 circles
3. add 2 additional points with pen tool
4. move anchor points
5. subtract top circle
6. the result repeat the same for right side